# i want to display marker in google map by giving lat lan values as input

Tags: android, google-maps

i am displaying lat lan values from message in list view, i want to display marker in google map when list item is clicked or touched in list view by givivng the Lat and Lan values.

```
public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            //Retriving Lat Lan from msg body
                String[] splitted = smsList.get( pos ).split("\n"); 
            String sender = splitted[0];

            String data= splitted[2];
            String[] latval=data.split(":");
            String lat=latval[1];//Lat Value 

            String data1 = splitted[3];
            String[] lanval=data1.split(":");

            String lan=lanval[1];//Lan Value



            Toast.makeText( this, lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            Toast.makeText( this, lan, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: Are you looking for this - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps ?

Comment: i want to call a method in the above method that will show marker in google map based on these latitude and longitude values

Comment: is ther any method to show google maps by providing la lan values